# Making a DOS-style window in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I'm trying emulate the MS-DOS command prompt on my website.  I don't need to accept keystrokes, but I'd like to append data at the bottom and optionally scroll upwards.

At first I looked at the asp:TextBox and asp:Label, but the flicker of using postbacks seemed to be too much.  I'm now considering DIV tags and Javascript where I simply update the InnerHTML property, but there too I get flicker, and have issues with scrolling.

What solution would you recommend in this situation?  Essentially I'm trying to count to infinity, with a 1 sec delay, only need the most current 300 or so entries, with the most current entry at the bottom of the screen.

Is this even possible with JS/CSS?

Comment: what/why are you doing postbacks?

Comment: @lincolnk Just experimenting with postbacks.  I want a retro feel, but not sure how 'retro' I want to go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you wish to make it a little more stylous ? :)

see this page...
http://www.klaus.dk/Some_unknown_page
or this one
http://www.harryovers.com/404.html?aspxerrorpath=/Account/LoginPartial

here is the javascript source code.

http://code.google.com/p/c64-404-page/

With a little change, you can append your text on this code :)

Answer (score 1):

I just built something very similar using jQuery.  You can use the [append method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add content to the bottom of your DIV.  You can then set the scrollTop attribute to keep things scrolled to the bottom as follows:

```
$("#someDiv").attr({ scrollTop: $("#someDiv").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

Comment: I'll need to learn scrollTop, thanks. Since I'm counting to infinity how would I chop off data that was previously appended a long time ago?  Otherwise I risk overloading the client.

Comment: What is the source of your data?

Comment: ...If I were to take this a step further, any idea how I could create a blinking cursor? Perhaps a second one line Div, and then use timer to change the text at a set frequency?

Answer (score 0):

I think "DOS-style window" is a bit misleading considering all you want to do is append text to a div and make sure it stays scrolled to the bottom.

```
function addLine(text) {

  var box = document.getElementById('DOSBox') //teehee

  var line = document.createElement('p');
  line.innerHTML = text;

  box.appendChild(line);

  box.scrollTop = box.scrollHeight;

}
```

And style it as such

```
#DOSBox {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 400px; width: 500px; /* or whatever */

  /* and if you want it to look DOS-like */
  background: #000;
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  font-family: fixedsys;
}

#DOSBox p {
  margin: 0;
}
```